# Every store have their own media folder?

Tags: magento-1.7, media

I have a code in Magento that I want to overwrite. Code can be found in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php`:

The code goes something like this :

```
protected function _construct()
{
    ...
    $this->_data['media_dir']   = $root.DS.'default_media';
    ...
}
```

I need to change default media, that every store have its own media directory. So i made a function:

```
public function getMediaFromStore()
{
    $fullMediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    echo substr(Mage::getBaseUrl($fullMediaUrl, strlen($baseUrl));
}
```

And then, instead of

```
$this->_data['media_dir']   = $root.DS.'default_media';
```

i put

```
$this->_data['media_dir']   = $root.DS.$this->getMediaFromStore();
```

and i got freaking error, that goes like this...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object in
>   /home/cofamedia/www/magento/app/Mage.php on line 328

And I'm stuck. Does any of you have some explanation how to go over this error. And do for every store their own media folder in Magento. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the full error stack trace?

Comment: @Tim What do you mean?

Comment: Ah, now I see that you got PHP fatal error and not Magento exception.

Comment: Incorrect use of substr()

Answer (score 1):

You have a child error in your method. Instead of echoing

```
echo substr(Mage::getBaseUrl($fullMediaUrl, strlen($baseUrl));
```

you should return the value

```
return substr(Mage::getBaseUrl($fullMediaUrl, strlen($baseUrl));
```

Comment: That is not it, neither, i realize that i have mistakes in function, but either way, same error showing up, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what is mean of your snippet? If you want different media url for every store you can do this logic with standard Magento functionality. Go to admin->system->config and open Web tab. Top left corner you can change store scope and you should set media url for every store differently via unsecure/secure field-set.

### Updated:

In my opinion you have more store with different domain name with one magento installation. And you want every store should has own media root named as domain name:

```
www.somestore.com -> somestore
www.anotherstore.com -> anotherstore
```

There is somestore, anotherstore are media folder names.
Use like as:

```
public function getMediaFromStore()
{
    $host=explode('.',$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
    return $host[count($host)-2]; 
}
```

Comment: No that is not it, when you change in admin panel, nothing happens, but thank you.

Comment: You mean media folder, not media url, right?

Comment: Yes, media folder.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes i have tried, but still the same error.

Comment: Check if this file is changed or nor: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php. In my opinion there is some error related to php syntax.